# What is the regex to remove the content inside brackets?

Tags: python, regex

I want to do something like this,

```
Alice in the Wonderland [1865] [Charles Lutwidge Dodgson] Rating 4.5/5
```

to

```
Alice in the Wonderland Rating 4.5/5
```

What is the regex command to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to escape the the brackets and use the non-greed modifier `?` with the catch-all expression `.+`.

```
>>> s = 'Alice in the Wonderland [1865] [Charles Lutwidge Dodgson] Rating 4.5/5'
>>> re.sub(r'\[.+?\]\s*', '', s)
'Alice in the Wonderland Rating 4.5/5'
```

Explanations:

- The `.` means any character and `+` one or more occurrences. This expression is "greedy" and will match everything (the rest of the string including any closing bracket) so you need the non-greedy modifier `?` to make it stop at the closing bracket. Note that `x?` means zero or one occurrences of "x", so context matters.
- Change it to `.*` if you want to catch "[]", `*` means zero or more occurrences
- The `\s` represents any space character

You can use the "negated" character class instead of `.+?` - the `[^x]` means `not "x"`, but the resulting expression is harder to read: `\[[^\]]+\]`.

Justhalf's observation is very pertinent: this one works as long as brackets are not nested.

Comment: I think it's better to use `*` instead of `+` in both places. Otherwise you don't match `[]` or `[foo]bar`

Answer (score 3):

Regex is not good for matching arbitrary number of open and closing parentheses, but if they are not nested, it can be accomplished with this regex:

```
import re
string = 'Alice in the Wonderland [1865] [Charles Lutwidge Dodgson] Rating 4.5/5'
re.sub('\[[^\]]+\]\s*','',string)
```

Note that it will also remove any space after the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> re.sub(r'\[[^]]*\]\s?' , '', 'Alice in the Wonderland [1865] [Charles Lutwidge Dodgson] Rating 4.5/5')
'Alice in the Wonderland Rating 4.5/5'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer lots of `[]` in your regex :)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Alice in the Wonderland [1865] [Charles Lutwidge Dodgson] Rating 4.5/5'
>>> re.sub('[[].*?[]]\s*', '', s)
'Alice in the Wonderland Rating 4.5/5'

>>> re.sub('[[][^]]*.\s*', '', s)
'Alice in the Wonderland Rating 4.5/5'
```

Reiterating what @justhalf said. Python regex are no good for nested `[`

Comment: Now I remember why I've stopped writing Perl in favor of Python: [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) :-)